# Does Genesis 1:29-31 leave any room for the existence of animal-based diets in the period between the Creation and the Fall?

Tags: genesis, creation, plants-and-animals, eden, fall

Genesis 1:29-31 (ESV):

> 29 And God said, “Behold, I have given you **every plant yielding seed** that is on the face of all the earth, and **every tree with seed in its fruit**. **You shall have them for food**. 30 And to every beast of the earth and to every bird of the heavens and to everything that creeps on the earth, everything that has the breath of life, I have given **every green plant for food**.” And it was so. 31 **And God saw everything that he had made, and behold, it was very good**. And there was evening and there was morning, the sixth day.

Is there any room for the possibility that animal flesh was eaten during this period? Was veganism the norm in the Garden of Eden before the fall?

Comment: Can you say why you think this passage *doesn't* leave room for that possibility?

Comment: @AnthonyBurg - because of objections raised to a similar question asked on Christianity: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/82586/what-is-an-overview-of-christian-viewpoints-on-why-god-would-approve-of-animal-b (notice the update and the close-votes)

Comment: @AnthonyBurg - Oh, I think I misunderstood you. You said why I think it *doesn't* leave room. Well, the text appears to say that people and animals are expected to adhere to a plant-based diet. If any of the two groups had the permission to kill animals for food, I would've expected that option to have been mentioned here too, but it wasn't.

Comment: Do vegetarians live longer than carnivores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of food listed for human consumption in Gen 1 consisted entirely of plant based food.  More specifically, to humans:

> Gen 1:28 - Then God said, “Behold, I have given you every seed-bearing
> plant on the face of all the earth, and every tree whose fruit
> contains seed. They will be yours for food.

For animals:

> Gen 1:30 - And to every beast of the earth and every bird of the air
> and every creature that crawls upon the earth—everything that has the
> breath of life in it—I have given every green plant for food.” And it
> was so.

Thus, there was a slight difference between human diets and animals diets: man's diet was seed bearing plants; animals were to eat great plants (there is a bit of overlap here but let's not get delayed with details).

It was only after the flood that animal flesh was permitted:

> Gen 9:3 - Everything that lives and moves will be food for you; just
> as I gave you the green plants, I **now** give you all things.

Comment: Ferns ([fiddleheads](https://www.soscuisine.com/recipe/buttered-fiddleheads)) are non-seed-bearing plants. Would they have been (and perhaps still are) forbidden as human food?

Comment: FYI: I asked [Does Genesis 1:29 forbid ferns (fiddleheads) as food?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/130489/does-genesis-129-forbid-ferns-fiddleheads-as-food/130490#130490) on Mi Yodea. It has one brief answer now (they *were* but *aren't* forbidden), with a referral to Ramban's commentary: [Genesis 1:29 with Ramban](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.1.29?ven=The_Contemporary_Torah,_Jewish_Publication_Society,_2006&lang=bi&with=Ramban&lang2=en).

Answer (score 2):

Life in Genesis 1 seems simple.

> 29 And God said, “Behold, I have given you every plant yielding **seed** that is on the face of all the earth, and every tree with **seed** in its fruit. You shall have them for food. 30 And to every beast of the earth and to every bird of the heavens and to everything that creeps on the earth, everything that has the breath of life, I have given every **green plant** for food.” And **it was so**.

Animals were not to be eaten by man or by other animals. And it was so. That's the normal practice.

Is there any room for the possibility that animal flesh was eaten during this period?

Any person or animal that did that would be abnormal behavior. I suppose that it was within man's power to do so.

> 28b Rule over the fish in the sea and the birds in the sky and over every living creature that moves on the ground.

I doubt that Adam or Eve ate animal meat before the fall.

Comment: Do you think animals were reproducing at this point?

Comment: 22God blessed them and said, “Be fruitful and increase in number and fill the water in the seas, and let the birds increase on the earth.” 23And there was evening, and there was morning—the fifth day.

Comment: That's interesting, because if there's no predation, you have to wonder what would keep the populations in check.

Comment: Interesting indeed.

Comment: We need to remember two things. 1. Scripture is not clear regarding the length of time this is referring to. 2. There's no reason to look for naturalistic explanations in this situation. Creation itself was a miraculous event, what would prevent God from sustaining his creation during this period?

Comment: @AnthonyBurg: *"That's interesting, because if there's no predation, you have to wonder what would keep the populations in check"* - as if predation was the only possible solution for overpopulation. Another option is to allow reproduction to occur only for a finite period of time and then stop it.

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator Right, so either a tight timeframe or a some way to 'stop it' - what's the way?

Comment: @AnthonyBurg - do you mean what method would God have chosen to keep overpopulation in check had Adam not sinned? I don't know, that's up to God. I was just trying to make the point that there are alternatives to predation if that's the goal.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a bilblical scholar, but believe this makes sense. I am a 20+ year ethical vegan.

References? The Bible tells us about what we are supposed to consume in early Genesis. The Bible also mentions the "giants", the offspring of the fallen angels. We are clearly told in Genesis that plant foods are "meat" for us.

Meat refers to solid foods, not animal flesh and blood. God created all, we are all Gods' children and God loves us all. It does not make sense to provide us with Gods' children so we can betray their trust, slit their throats while they suffer, and consume the dead. How did we consume flesh and blood in the first place?.

The watchers, the fallen angels, mated with human women against Gods' wishes. Their hybrid offspring, the Nephilim, had 6 fingers and 6 toes, were huge and had voracious appetites. Plants did not satisfy them so they ate non-human animals and human animals as well. They taught humans to do things God never wanted us to know; how to forge iron and make weapons of war, how to kill, make fire, slaughter, cook, and eat animals. Before they taught this to us we were all raw plant eaters and vegans. These awful habits and hybrid entities were the reason for the Great flood. These habits polluted humanity. But, not all hybrids were killed, many remained, and humanity has been eating a violent diet and destroying the world ever since. It is considered by some to be a luciferian diet of eating the dead. This video helps to explain [this Biblical-vegan perspective](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTeQ0UKK-lM) further.

Comment: Actually, after the great flood (Gen 9:3-5), God told Noah and his 3 sons that all animals were theirs to eat. However, the animals' blood (their life) could not be touched. https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+9%3A3-5&version=NASB

Comment: Welcome to Hermeneutics! Regardless of whether others agree with this answer, this has reasonable ideas to consider. But, it is very important that we cite chapter-and-verse. Please, at least do a basic Google search for chapter-verse references for your three ideas in the "References?" paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

A legal maxim: "that which is not forbidden is allowed." But this begs many questions, for no moral commandments were given in Eden, yet no one would argue that murder or adultery was allowed [I hope]. In Jewish tradition there is much debate about which foods are allowed and which not. But Adam and Eve's diet is probably irrelevant for those of us who dwell outside the Gates of Eden.